When should java.sql.Statement.isClosed() throw an SQLException?
The API doc states @throws SQLException if a database access error occurs. Does this mean that implementations could/should also check whether the underlying database connection is working rather than just returning true if the client side state of the object isn't closed?

it means the implementation can check the connection, not that it must. I would expect such check only if there are some cleaning up that must still have an open connection


Does this mean that implementations could/should also check whether the underlying database connection is working rather than just returning true if the client side state of the object isn't closed?

It means that some JDBC driver implementations1 might (or could) check an underlying database connection.  If it does, and a database access error occurs, then the exception may be thrown.
It does NOT mean that it should (or must) check the connection.
I won't speculate on why a JDBC driver would need to check the connection.  Or even whether such a driver actually exists.  For most JDBC driver implementations, a client-side check should be sufficient, and the exception wouldn't be thrown by isClosed()

As to these followups in comments:

how would you generally handle that exception without knowing the underlying driver?

That will depend on the application.  If there is nothing better, the application could log the exception and exit.

how would you implement a driver in accordance with the interface documentation?

One way would be to not check the connection and not throw the exception.  That conforms with the interface documentation.  Please see above where I wrote about what spec is saying and what it is not saying.
But as I said above, I am not going to speculate on why a (hypothetical) JDBC driver would need to check the connection.

1 - I am using the words "should", "could", "may", "might" and "must" in their normal English sense.

I'm not sure how your "No" is meant, isn't "might" essentially equivalent to "could" in this context?
Perhaps the question should include what the openness of a Statement entails in this context: @return true if this {@code Statement} object is closed; false if it is still open
My understanding is that this is purely related to the state of the object, but this might be overinterpretation on my end.

As for your foot note, how would you generally handle that exception without knowing the underlying driver, and how would you implement a driver in accordance with the interface documentation? There's of course the pragmatic approach to just consider this a quirk in the interface specification, but this is basically what I'm trying to figure out, whether this should be considered or just shrugged off.

You could probably update your question with more specific information.  The question as it is now sounds like a very general informational question, something a user of a database driver might be curious about.  If you're implementing a driver, I think you should break down the question into smaller chunks and ask specific questions about that.

@makrom The JDBC API tries to accommodate a wide range of situations, including native drivers (type 2 drivers), and middleware drivers (type 3, hardly exist in practice though). It is entirely possible that checking if a statement is closed could result in some native library error, or that a remote request needs to be done to the middleware to check the actual statement state, which could result in a network or other type of error.  This means that a check if the statement is closed may produce an error, which means an exception will be thrown to report it.

I see what you mean but I left the question intentionally as generic as it is in order to get answers for anyone who is interested in this subject as well. As for your proposed situations for such exceptions to happen, from my understanding native library errors aren't within the scope of what SQLExceptions should cover, though there's definitely room for interpretation. But throwing such an exception for something unrelated to the connection that the statement is executed against seems a bit random, that would also justify including things like IOException for the same reason.

And don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to be argumentative, I really appreciate the input. I think it's quite possible that this is just one of those question for which there isn't a precise answer as the actual reason has a large legacy aspect.

@makrom (a) java.sql.SQLException would subsume what you might think of as a IOException. The Javadoc notes that info needed by the SQL programmer should be included within the SQLException.  And exceptions can be chained. (b) No, not legacy. The world of SQL is quite broad and more diverse than you may be imagining with only a Type 4 JDBC driver making a direct connection to a MySQL server in mind.

@makrom A java.sql.Statement is a resource ("opened" & "closed") because it may be interacting with a SQL source or SQL server. Compare that to  a java.sql.DataSounce which does not interact with a SQL source/server, is never “opened” or “closed”, and is not a resource.

@Basil Bourque Are you suggesting that the definition of .isClosed() leaves room for interpretation to include evaluating the state of the associated resource rather than just the object itself?
Perhaps my interpretation is too strict, but to me this strongly hints towards checking a local state: A Statement is closed if the method close has been called on it, or if it is automatically closed. So in theory the return value should not depend on the state of the resource, even if it's disconnected or otherwise broken.

"I see what you mean but I left the question intentionally as generic as it is in order to get answers for anyone who is interested in this subject as well."  - Not biting.  If you have specific questions, I suggest you actually ask them ... specifically.

@ Stephen C I think my question was as specific as it was intended to be. The aspect that might have been left vague is my intention behind asking that question. My understanding is that this is in line with SO's desired FAQ character.

For someone who is "not trying to be argumentative" you are doing a lot of arguing :-)

"from my understanding native library errors aren't within the scope of what SQLExceptions should cover" You'd be wrong, because that is definitely something that would need to be reported with a SQLException. Same goes for IOExceptions, because in case you haven't noticed: JDBC only allows SQLException, so any exception occurring within the driver, or communicating to a native or remote layer should result in a SQLException, so you as the user of the driver know something is wrong or otherwise broken.

@Mark Rotteveel I'm sorry, I meant within the definition of when .isClosed() is supposed to throw an SQLException.

Even so, your understanding is still wrong.  Nothing in the javadoc mentions native libraries.  Let alone that exceptions thrown by them are "out of scope".  You are making all sorts of assumption about how a driver might be implemented that the spec says nothing about.   The spec simply says "when a database access error occurs".  That's it.  Nothing else.

@Steven C I didn't mean to bring up native libraries. Of course they could be relevant, but only in case they happen when trying to access the DB as per definition of the API.

I think this is a wrong question to ask, JDBC nor Java itself doesn't really force you to do anything, there's no JDBC validation badge one can get, so you can always expect the unexpected when using JDBC methods.
A lot of implementations don't even implement all the methods of the interfaces but rather just crash.
If you're writing one yourself, you should try to follow the intent of the docs which says:

Retrieves whether this Statement object has been closed

If that means throwing exceptions or just reading from variable is up to you. But you probably want to make things easier for consumers of your drivers, by returning reasonable values and not call the db unnecessarily.
You should also try to implements things the way other drivers already implemented them, because the consumers will unlikely have custom code for every driver.
If you're a consumer of drivers yourself, calling isClosed might be an error in itself, because you should know if you have handle on the lifecycle of your Statement, or the answer might not help you, because the truth can change after the call has returned.
Finally, for what it's worth, I checked SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite drivers and none of them made db calls in the isClosed method.

Formally, if a driver doesn't implement methods and just "crashes", it is not a JDBC-compliant driver. A driver is only allowed to not implement a method (and throw SQLFeatureNotSupportedException) for methods that are explicitly declared optional in the JDBC specification, or allow throwing of SQLFeatureNotSupportedException in the JDBC API javadoc.

The isClosed() method might throw a SQLException if there is a database access issue when checking the statements state. That said, most JDBC drivers (like MySQL and PostgreSQL) just check the local state and don't actually hit the database, so this exception is pretty rare.
If you're writing a driver, stick to the APIs intent: keep it simple and avoid unnecessary DB calls. As a user, it's usually better to manage your statement lifecycle directly instead of relying too much on isClosed().

Yes but the question comes down to why an implementation of a Statement would possibly use a DB connection to check whether either .isClosed() was called or it was auto-closed. The idea that it is intended for implementations of Statement that are retrieved from a DB seems so random, then why not include exceptions for other implementations that use a web service and so?
